# How to read out HDIO_GET_IDENTITY using Perl

Tags: linux, perl, fcntl

I would like to read out HDIO_GET_IDENTITY on Linux using perl. I'm trying to use the Fcntl module but I found the Perl module documentation not very explanatory. Can anyone provide me pointers how to do this?

https://metacpan.org/module/Fcntl

Comment: Check this out. http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/include/uapi/linux/hdreg.h#L344

Comment: So, how do I read this data using Fcntl in perl?

Comment: Sharing this Question, definitely you'll get the answer.